# Generate substrings using sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set

My friend was asked a questions in his Interview.

How can you find the all possible substrings of a given string ?
I know this can be solved using many techniques, but later he was given a hint which was to use sets for it.

I could not figure out how to do it using sets. Can someone please shed some light on it?

Comment: is that supposed to be time or space efficient?

Comment: Set ensures uniqueness..

Comment: There were no more details about time or space were asked

Answer (score 3):

Sets, by definition, only include one copy of an element. Using sets to solve this problem would remove the possibility of including duplicate substrings in your output set.

Lets say you're iterating over this string:

```
aabbaa
```

Looking for substrings of length two, and adding them to a set as you go.

You'd find:

```
aa
ab
bb
ba
aa
```

The first and last of these are duplicates, so one would be discarded.

Comment: I see. Similar can be done by putting output strings in hashmap , right ?

Comment: @AmolPatil A HashMap (at least in Java, I'm not sure about other languages) uses key-value pairs to store data. I don't think that would be a sensible choice of data structure for this problem. You could use each substring as both the key and the value, but that would be an odd way to do things.

Comment: The implementation of HashSet (in Java) is actually to create a HashMap<K, Object>, where all keys in the set map to the same dummy object, so yes, you could do it with a HashMap directly (but it would be more awkward).

Comment: @BrianWillis Python's builtin `set` is implemented using a hashmap. Java's `HashSet` is implemented using a `HashMap`. C++ might be the odd one out, as `std::set` are "typically implemented using binary search trees", according to the documentation; so, using a hashmap doesn't seem particularly odd (although if the language provides both "set" and "hashmap" in its standard library, it's probably best to trust the library and use "set", if only because it will make the intent and logic of the algorithm more obvious).